# Check if controller is part of specific "controller group"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC im overwriting the OnException, so I can do some custom error handling on exceptions. One thing I would like to do here is to log from what area in the webapplication the error happend.

For example we have Webshop and Administration areas in the webapplications. Then I would like to identify if the exception comes from a Webshop controller or an Administration controller. This is what I have:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception != null)
            {
                ErrorTargetType targetErrorType = ErrorTargetType.DipService;

                if (filterContext.Controller is CatalogController)
                    targetErrorType = ErrorTargetType.WebshopInterface;

                LogException(filterContext.Exception, targetErrorType);
            }
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
```

It works fine but I would like do the if statement on a collection of Administration controllers insted. Does ASP.NET MVC have some standard functionality which provides all the controllers in the webapplication in a collection, if so, how do I separate the Webshop controllers from the Administration controllers?

Comment: Have you considered using the namespace of the `filterContext.Controller`? e.g. `filterContext.Controller.GetType().FullName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all the controllers in the webapplication in a collection

A *collection of controllers* or *controllers group* is a notion that doesn't exist in ASP.NET MVC nor it makes much sense. The fact that you call `ControllerA`, `ControllerB` and `ControllerC` being part of *Administration* is a notion that only you have defined. The sole notion of *Administration* hardly makes any sense in ASP.NET MVC. In ASP.NET MVC you have Models, Views and of course Controllers.

> if so, how do i seperate the Webshop controllers from the Administration controllers?

Make them derive from a common base controller or make them implement a [marker interface](http://elegantcode.com/2008/07/30/marker-interfaces-and-c-attributes/).

Comment: Great answer. Sometimes stuff like that just slips my mind when answering questions here. I would have probably gone the interface route in my project. :)

Comment: I reason i want to do this is because i need to log where the error happends, so i can provide the user with a error code which they can supply to our support. Then our support can submit the error to the correct employee.